# Permission error without a file extension

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, file-extension

I have an python program that scans all files in a directory, but when I want to open a file with no extension like `C:\path\to\file\actual file`, then python gives me a permission denied error.How can I fix that?

What I mean with no extension is that it does not have .exe or .txt or something like that.How can I read files without adding extensions to the files manually?

This is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scan.py", line 152, in <module>
    file = open(i,'r')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\path\\to\\file\\my_file'
```

Comment: What makes you think that this problem has anything to do with the file's extension? Because it looks like a permissions problem to me.

Comment: Are you sure that *C:\\path\\to\\file\\my_file* isn't actually a *dir*? Also, it's missing the last *bkslash*.

Comment: @aran-fey i have the right permisions

Comment: @Cristifati my_file is the file name but it has not got an extension

Comment: Python really doesn't care about extensions, they are just part of the string making up the filename. Your problem lies elsewhere, the OS is stating your code doesn't have permission to access that path, plain and simple.

Comment: It looks as if the program is trying to read something it can not read, ergo you either do not have the file, which would cause a different error, you are trying to read a folder, or you are trying to access a file that is secured by the system admin, not the user admin

Comment: it is my own folder

Comment: The missing backslash seems the most likely problem: how does `i` get set?

Comment: @Lua just because "it's your own folder" doesn't mean you have read permissions on all the directory's contents (nor that the running process has the same perrms as you actually - if it's launched by the system, it can well run as another user, which is often the case for system services)

Comment: @chepner: this is an error message output, changed to swap out the actual filename for a sample filename. The OP simply forgot to double that last slash there, because Python itself would *never, ever* produce a string representation with `\m`; there is no such escape sequence in strings.

Comment: @chepner it is from a generator that gets all the files in that folder

Comment: @martijnpieters also tried that also does not work

Comment: Sorry, what did you try? I didn’t make any suggestions.

Comment: i try to read the file my_file

Comment: No file extension on the file means either way, the file can not be opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have zero idea why it does not work other than what my comment stated, however this program will work for windows.

```
import os
s = "H:\path\to\file\ActualFile"
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(s):
    for file in files:
        try:
            GatheredFiles = (os.path.join(subdir, file))
        except PermissionError:
            print("You do not have permision to go in here"))
            break
```

Edit: added the try statement

Comment: where is the try?

Comment: yeah where is the try: except: statement?

Comment: Going to be honest, it was quite easy to see where I didn't put the try due to the code writen.